# how to create rpm package from python script

Tags: python, package, rpm, packaging

I want to create rpm package from python script `script.py`. I found ways to create rpm package from python packages but not from python script. I could create debian package from python script so I am hoping there must be way for rpm package as well. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you have a setup.py yet?

Comment: nope I don't have `setup.py`

Comment: How did you create the debian package?

Comment: @FredrikWendt I followed this [way](https://askubuntu.com/a/91616)